# Unable to debug python code in vs code - code gives exception at the import library

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

num_house = 160
np.random.seed(42)
house_size = np.random.randint(low=1000, high=3500, size=num_house)
```

I am trying to debug this python code in visual studio code. I have selected the right configuration (Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)). I have set my breakpoint on the last line. When i run from the debug console, my code fails giving me a ModuleNotFoundError. But I am able to execute this program in the terminal. How do I debug this code in vs code?

Comment: What version of Python are you using in the terminal, and what version does vs code use?

Comment: python version 3.6.7

Comment: They are both that version?  You're sure?

Comment: I saw that there were 2 python versions installed on my machine. so I uninstalled v3.7 and now I am able to debug. Thanks for your help